# Android Toast showing too late after clicking on a button

Tags: android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

Please i need your help !!

when i finished my Android app i discovered that all my Toast in the app doesn't show at the moment when i click on the button but too late!

i didn't know why !
and i didn't know which part of code to screen to you !

this some of code :

```
envoyer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);
                v.startAnimation(buttonClick);

                if (nom_compte.getText().toString().equals("") || num_compte.getText().toString().equals("") || num_tel.getText().toString().equals("") || (dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Votre banque..")) ) {
                    Toast.makeText(Get_My_Money_Activity.this, "remplir tous les champs !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    MyAsyncTaskresources2 attemptLogin2= new MyAsyncTaskresources2();
                    attemptLogin2.execute("http://example.com/demandes_de_paiement.php?id_user="+session.getId()+"&nom_compte="+URLEncoder.encode(nom_compte.getText().toString())+"&num_compte="+URLEncoder.encode(num_compte.getText().toString())+"&num_tel="+URLEncoder.encode(num_tel.getText().toString())+"&nom_banque="+URLEncoder.encode(dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: How long that you consider it "too late"?

Comment: showing after 15 sec

Comment: Did you try `setDuration(1000) ` for your button click animation?

Comment: no i didn't try it ....ok i am gonna try it right now

Comment: setDuration() doesn't accepte a value ....accept just Toast.Toast.LENGTH_...

Comment: No, no, `buttonClick.setDuration(1000)`

Comment: check after commenting animation code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved the problem.

it was in my service notification where i put a Toast empty and who run every 2 sec so block the background for the other Toast.

Answer (score 0):

You can set time as you want-

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",1000).show();
```

or watever value you want to set.